# How R2 linear transformed into a (2x2) matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb R^3\to M(2,\mathbb R)$  be a linear transformation defined by $$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x&x-z\\ \:0&y\end{pmatrix}$$

So how do I count the dimension of kernel? Is it even possible to have a transformation like wise?
I am not good in this chapter, please enlighten me.

Comment: Is it well defined ?

Comment: the kernel is trivial

Comment: Your question is wrong.

Comment: it is the only information given in the question, how do i count dimension from that?

Comment: @AmanPandey It is a final assessment, I was wondering the same thing, but i am not sure about it

Comment: Dimension of what?

Comment: of kernel, i will add it up

Comment: Kernel is of dimension zero

Comment: @Noobmathematician can you enlighten me?

Comment: @Seow I have answered it for you .

Comment: @Noobmathematician thank you sir

Comment: U r most welcome 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y,z)\in \ker T $ then you have

$$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ \:0&0\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}x&x-z\\ \:0&y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ \:0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$Then $x=0$, $x-z=0$ and $y=0$
and hence you have $\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\\end{pmatrix}$.

So the kernel is of dimension zero.

Comment: Iam a new user, i wil return to upvote when i have enough rep.

Comment: Thanks ! Have a happy stacks experience